# Iterate array on current position

Tags: jquery

I've got an array with letters. With the right and left key I want to navigate left and right, on enter key, I want the current position (or letter) to be activated and then with up and down keys change the letter at the current position. When pressing enter again I want to leave the activated state and be able to move left and right again. The left and right navigation works but the up and down arrows changes all the letters at the same time. I guess I need to use `$(this)` in some way. I'm sorry if my code looks messy, I really can't get the pieces together for this. I would be very happy if someone could point me in the right direction!

```
    // $( document ).ready()
    var letters = ['','a','b','c','d','e'];

    var letterIndex = 0;

    $('a:first').focus();

            $(document).keydown(function(e) {

                    e.preventDefault();

                    var keyCode = e.which;
                        arrow = {up: 38, down: 40, right: 39, left: 37, enter: 13};

                    switch(e.which) {
                        case arrow.up:
                            letterIndex = letterIndex + 1;
                            $(this).find('a').html(letters[letterIndex]);
                        break;

                        case arrow.down:
                            letterIndex = letterIndex - 1;
                            $(this).find('a').html(letters[letterIndex]);
                        break;

                        case arrow.right:
                            $('a:focus').closest('li').next().find('a').focus();
                        break;

                        case arrow.left:
                            $('a:focus').closest('li').prev().find('a').focus();
                        break;

                        case arrow.enter:
                            $(this).find('a').focus().toggleClass('highlight');
                        break;
                    }

            });
        });
```

HTML

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="">a</a></li>
   <li><a href="">b</a></li>
   <li><a href="">c</a></li>
   <li><a href="">d</a></li>
</ul>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2qtx0sL/)

Comment: fiddle would be nice, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you want.

#### Improvements:

**1.** `letterIndex` should not be global vairable as each link element maintains its
    own state.

**2.**  Bind the event to each link element and use `$(this)` rather searching the event owner using `find()`.

---

```
var letters = ['','a','b','c','d','e'];

$('a:first').focus();

$("a").on('keydown', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var keyCode = e.which;
        arrow = {up: 38, down: 40, right: 39, left: 37, enter: 13};

    //each link has its own state so the variable needs to be local like this
    letterIndex = letters.indexOf($(this).html());  

    //loop index from max to min
    if(letterIndex == letters.length)
         letterIndex = -1;

    switch(e.which) {
        case arrow.up:
            letterIndex = letterIndex + 1;
            $(this).html(letters[letterIndex]);
        break;

        case arrow.down:
            letterIndex = letterIndex - 1;
            $(this).html(letters[letterIndex]);
        break;

        case arrow.right:
            $(this).closest('li').next().find('a').focus();
        break;

        case arrow.left:
            $(this).closest('li').prev().find('a').focus();
        break;

        case arrow.enter:
            $(this).focus().toggleClass('highlight');
        break;
    }

});
```

Comment: I kind of understand, but I'm really confused in how to use 'this'. What will I do with the if-statement?

Comment: Just replace the code u post on ur question with what I answered.

Comment: you well come my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Save `a:first` in a variable so you can use it from within nested functions (in your case `$(document).keydown()`).

```
$('a:first').focus();

        var $this = $(this); // save this element for later use

        $(document).keydown(function(e) {

                e.preventDefault();

                var keyCode = e.which;
                    arrow = {up: 38, down: 40, right: 39, left: 37, enter: 13};

                switch(e.which) {
                    case arrow.up:
                        letterIndex = letterIndex + 1;
                        $this.html(letters[letterIndex]); // use it here
                    break;

                ...

        }
```